# How to change the model of a component in another module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a module that renders a map with some icons. 
If I click an icon on the map I want to update another view with the restaurant data I find in my restaurant list with the ID of the clicked icon.
I have an update function for that purpose, but I don't know how to access the function.
I render both of the components in the app.component.html.

I tried to google the problem, but I don't really know what I should search for, because it's my first time working with angular. (doing this for learning purposes)

I have a main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
    })

    export class AppComponent  {
      title = 'PandasRestaurantApp';

    }
```

where I render my other 2 views:

```
<vo-ui-osm-view 
[showDebugInfo]="false"
[showControlsZoom]="false"
[showControlsCurrentLocation]="true"
(addressChanged)="onAddressChange($event)"
>
</vo-ui-osm-view>
<app-company-details></app-company-details>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the osm view is rendering the map with icons of restaurants.
If I click on a restaurant icon:

```
  mapOnClick(evt) {
    const map = evt.map;
    var restaurants = this.restaurants;

      //this bit checks if user clicked on a feature
      const iconDetails = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature) {
        console.log(feature.c);
        var id = feature.c.split("_")[0];
        console.log(id);
        var restaurant = restaurants.find((restaurant) =>{
          return restaurant.id == id;
        });

        return restaurant;
      })
      // here I want to call the set function of the other component
    }
```

I want to update the model of the other component with the found restaurant.

The other view has a function (setRestaurant) to do so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-details',
  templateUrl: './company-details.module.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-details.module.component.sass']
})
export class CompanyDetails {


  @Output()
  restaurants : Array<Restaurant>;

  setRestaurant(restaurant){
    this.restaurants = new Array<Restaurant>();
    this.restaurants.push(restaurant);
  }

  constructor() {
    var restaurants = new restaurantDetailsService();
    this.restaurants = restaurants.get();
   }


}
```

The view is a simple for loop over all the restaurants in the restaurants array:

```
<li *ngFor="let r of restaurants; let i = index">
        <b>id: {{r.id}}</b> <br>
        <b>Name: {{r.name}}</b><br>
        <b>Strasse: {{r.street}}</b><br>
        <b>Hausnummer: {{r.streetNumber}}</b><br>
        <b>Zusatz: {{r.streetExtra}}</b><br>
        <b>Postleitzahl: {{r.postalcode}}</b><br>
        <b> longitude: {{r.longitude}}</b><br>
        <b> latitude: {{r.latitude}}</b><br>
        <b>  Tagesangebot: 

        <li *ngFor = "let m of r.mealPlan">
            <b>Mahlzeit: {{m.mealName}}</b><br>
            <b>Preis: {{r.price}}</b><br>

        </li></b>



    </li>
```

I expect to update the view with the found restaurant, but I don't know how to archive this.

**Edit:**

@Sajeetharan I've created this service:

```
 import { Injectable, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
    import { Restaurant } from '../../Model/restaurant.model';
    import { Meal } from '../../Model/meal.model';

    @Injectable ({  
      providedIn: 'root'  
    })  

    export class RestaurantDetailsService implements OnInit {  

        @Output()
        restaurants: Array<Restaurant>;  

        @Output()
        restaurant: Restaurant;

        constructor(){
                this.restaurants = [  
                {  
                    id: 'r1',
                    name: 'Restaurant1',
                    street: "Händelstrasse",
                    streetExtra: "b",
                    streetNumber: "7",
                    postalcode: "18069",
                    latitude: 54.22046600000008,
                    longitude: 9.706516000000008,
                    daylieSpecial: [new Meal("TagesMal",["Zutat1", "Zutat2"], 12)],
                    mealPlan: [ new Meal("IrgendEinMal",["Zutat4", "Kaese"], 10),
                                new Meal("HackZwiebel",["Hack", "Zwiebel"], 3) ]

                },
                {
                    id: 'r2',
                    name: 'Restaurant2',
                    street: "Strasse",
                    streetExtra: "b",
                    streetNumber: "10",
                    postalcode: "18069",
                    latitude: 54.22006740000008,
                    longitude: 9.706316300000008,
                    daylieSpecial: [new Meal("TagesMal",["Zutat1", "Zutat2"], 12)],
                    mealPlan: [ new Meal("IrgendEinMal",["Zutat4", "Kaese"], 10),
                                new Meal("HackZwiebel",["Hack", "Zwiebel"], 3) ]
                }
            ];  
        }

        ngOnInit(){
        }



     getRestaurant(): Observable<Restaurant>{
                return of(this.restaurant);
            }
            setRestaurant(restaurant){
                this.restaurant = restaurant;
            }

            getRestaurantList(): Restaurant [] {  
                return this.restaurants;


       }  

}
```

My company-details component locks like this now:

```
   import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter , ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { Restaurant } from '../../../Model/restaurant.model'
    import { RestaurantDetailsService } from '../../Services/restaurantDetails.service'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-company-details',
      templateUrl: './company-details.module.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./company-details.module.component.sass']
    })
    export class CompanyDetails {



      restaurant: Restaurant;

  constructor(private restaurantDetailsService: RestaurantDetailsService) {
    this.restaurantDetailsService.getRestaurant()
        .subscribe(restaurant => this.restaurant = restaurant);

   }


    }
```

and the view is changed to this:

```
 <b>id: {{restaurant.id}}</b> <br>
    <b>Name: {{restaurant.name}}</b><br>
    <b>Strasse: {{restaurant.street}}</b><br>
    <b>Hausnummer: {{restaurant.streetNumber}}</b><br>
    <b>Zusatz: {{restaurant.streetExtra}}</b><br>
    <b>Postleitzahl: {{restaurant.postalcode}}</b><br>
    <b> longitude: {{restaurant.longitude}}</b><br>
    <b> latitude: {{restaurant.latitude}}</b><br>
    <b>  Tagesangebot: 

    <li *ngFor = "let m of r.mealPlan">
        <b>Mahlzeit: {{m.mealName}}</b><br>
        <b>Preis: {{r.price}}</b><br>

    </li></b>
```

Now, if I update the service with the setRestaurant function in the other component, nothing is happening in my view:

```
   mapOnClick(evt) {
    const self = this;
    const map = evt.map;

      //this bit checks if user clicked on a feature
      const iconDetails = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature) {
        var id = feature.c.split("_")[0];

        var restaurant = self.restaurantDetailsService.getRestaurantList().find(
          (restaurant) =>{

            return restaurant.id == id;
        });

        return restaurant;
      })

      self.restaurantDetailsService.setRestaurant(iconDetails);
      console.log(self.restaurantDetailsService.getRestaurant())
    }
```

Could you help me out in what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`SharedService`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). You can use BehaviourSubject, This means that new subscribers will always get the last value emitted synchronously.

Comment: I've edited my question, could you take a lock at the code? Edit: If I click on an Icon, I get the restaurant that I want.